# Using Web3.js in a Google Cloud Function - SyntaxError: Unexpected token '||=' in Web3Js

Tags: web3.js

When attempting to upload a typescript function to a Google cloud function, I run into

```
Detailed stack trace: /workspace/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/lib/index.cjs.js:644
        keyMeta.isSigner ||= accountMeta.isSigner;
                         ^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '||='
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1029:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1078:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1143:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:979:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:819:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1003:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:107:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/workspace/node_modules/@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata/dist/src/generated/index.js:18:19)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1143:10)
```

This function/code works as intended when compiled locally with tsc+node index.js.

My understanding is that cloud functions dockerize your code, then run it in a container. Would appreciate if anyone had any direction to go on this.

Answer (score 2):

Update: Turns out the issue was my CloudFunction was using Nodejs14, and I needed to specify it to use Nodejs15+.